# Error validating module $_GET $_POST, $_REQUEST

Tags: magento2, error, marketplace, http-request

I have errors validating my module in Marketplace Magento 2.4

Direct use of $_GET Superglobal detected.
Direct use of $_POST Superglobal detected.
Direct use of $_REQUEST Superglobal detected.

how should I use those methods correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use magento method like this :

```
<?php namespace Vendor\Extension\Yourcontrollerfolder; 

class Yourcontrollerclass
{ 

      protected $request; 

      public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) 
     { 
           $this->request = $request; 
     } 

     public function Yourfunction() 
     { 
          //POST VALUE USE THIS CODE
          $postData = $this->request->getPost();
          
     } 
}
```

Comment: $_GET = $request->getParams()
$_POST = $request->getPost()
$_REQUEST = $request

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php namespace Vendor\Extension\Yourcontrollerfolder;     

 class Yourcontrollerclass
 { 

  protected $request; 

  public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) 
 { 
       $this->request = $request; 
 } 

 public function Yourfunction() 
 { 
      $GET = $request->getParams();
      $POST = $request->getPost();
      $REQUEST = $request;
      
   } 
}
```